# React functional component props sort alphabetically. (At the definition side)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, prettier

I know an eslint rule, to sort the component props at the usage side. 
Like `<Cmp alpha={true} beta={true} />` ([rule](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-sort-props.md))

But is there a rule, what sorts the `props` from the definition side? 
Like: 
`const Cmp = ({ beta, alpha = false }) => null;` should be `const Cmp = ({ alpha = false, beta }) => null;`

Comment: No such rule exists, so I made one at [PR](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/pull/2854).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such a rule exists, so I made one at [PR](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/pull/2854). This remains to be accepted and pushed so will take some time.

Comment: awesome, thanx a lot